# Discrete-time plots in Matlab?

Tags: matlab, plot

I'm just trying to program a function for a discrete-time unit step from say, -10 to 10, so that I can perform other operations on it to test some things such as u[n-1], u[2n], u[-n], etc. I haven't used Matlab in quite a while and can't seem to get it working. Or is it easier to use WolframAlpha for this? Would someone show me how to do this with either way please?

Comment: [`stairs`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/stairs.html)?

Comment: 0 at t<0 and 1 at t>= 1 for integer values and zero everywhere else

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
t=-10:10;

stepFCT=zeros(1,length(t));

%%%%%%u[n-1]%%%%%%

for i=1:length(t);
    if t(i)-1>=0
        stepFCT(i)=1;
    else
    end
end

figure(1)
stem(t,stepFCT)

%%%%%%u[2n]%%%%%%

stepFCT=zeros(1,length(t));


for i=1:length(t);
    if 2*t(i)>=0
        stepFCT(i)=1;
    else
    end
end

figure(2)
stem(t,stepFCT)

%%%%%%u[-n]%%%%%%

stepFCT=zeros(1,length(t));


for i=1:length(t);
    if -t(i)>=0
        stepFCT(i)=1;
    else
    end
end

figure(3)
stem(t,stepFCT)
```

Please try these codes.